# Custom actions will not show up in Thunar context menu under "send to"

Tags: xfce, thunar, thunar-custom-actions

I have created a desktop file for a custom action and installed it to /usr/share/Thunar/sendto/ but it does not show up in the "send to" part of the context menu in Thunar. I have also created a folder ~/.local/share/Thunar/sendto and put it in there with no luck. Furthermore, I have deleted the action "mail recipient" from the first of these folders and it no longer shows in the context menu, suggesting that that is the correct folder. This is the code for the desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Exec=~/.Dropbox-Uploader/dropbox_uploader.sh upload %F %N
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Numix-Circle/scalable/apps/dropbox.svg
Name=Dropbox
```

This works fine when the command is used as a standard custom action. Why won't it appear in the context menu under "send to"?

---

Update: commands with "ln" show up fine. Is this a necessary inclusion?

Answer (score 0):

For the Exec key set the absolute path to the home directory instead of using the tilde (~)

Per the freedesktop [Desktop Entry Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables):

> The executable program can either be specified with its full path or with the name of the executable only. If no full path is provided the executable is looked up in the $PATH environment variable used by the desktop environment.